# How to query child component injected by *ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular

query against templates injected by template outlet seems not to work, below is a an example, I am injecting child component as template input into parent component, but not able to query that component using @ViewChild..

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjqkbn

Comment: why do you want to do that way?  Use input property binding ref

Comment: @chellappan Component reuse, i am making slider, can you recomend me ready to use package ?

Comment: do you want me to suggest?

Comment: @Chellappan yeah, manually making it  took much time than i expected

Comment: Try material: https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview

Answer (score 0):

Need to access the ref element from app component and pass it down to parent component

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zbv23x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.ts)

```
<app-parent [childTpl]="childElement"></app-parent>
<app-child #child></app-child> 

export class AppComponent  { 
  @ViewChild('child', { read: ElementRef }) childElement: ElementRef;

   ngOnInit(){
      console.log(this.childElement.nativeElement.innerHTML)
    }
}
```

Comment: The question states to query child while it reside inside a ngtemplate

Comment: not sure we can access the element through `TemplateRef`